# comparing the address of string with NULL

Tags: c++

I came across something similar to this reviewing some code:

```
std::string mystring;
if (&mystring != NULL)
{
   DoSomething();  
}
```

Does this make any sense? could somebody explain some use case of this?

Comment: Unless `string` is a class with overloaded `operator&`, condition is always `true`.

Comment: No, string is the standard string from the STL

Comment: "across something similar" Or post the real code.

Comment: The code is equal semantically, I just removed the around logic and kept the interesting part.

Comment: As `std::string` doesn't overload `operator&`, the condition is unneeded.

Comment: @redobot We need [MCVE]'s here, not your interpretation of the code. Yes, the code you posted is nonsensical. For all we know, the real code isn't nonsensical. We're not psychic.

Comment: I know .. but code is for a private company so I can't post it. Sorry for that.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper: that would not be the first time that scories of different maintenance layers leave nonsensical code in real apps...

Comment: Yep .. it was so strange to me that I couldn't understand what hell is the condition trying to check!

Comment: Might be the writer of code would have through `&mystring` would give access to internal buffer similar to `std::vector`. And checking `!= NULL` to ensure its valid object.

Comment: @sameerkn For the record, `&vec` for a `std::vector<anything> vec` most definitely does *not* give the address of the internal buffer.

Comment: @Angew: Correct. I meant &vec[0]. But still this would be correct in case of `std::string`. Also writer might have thought *when `(arr+0)` is same as `arr` in case of `char arr[n]`, so `&mystring` would be same as `&mystring[0]` assuming `&mystring` returns the internal buffer.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the code you showed, the comparison doesn't make any sense whatsoever and will always evaluate to true.

My wild guess:

- `mystring` was originally a `char*` (maybe c-code).
- Someone refactored it blindly to a `std::string`.
- That lead to a compiler error and to silence it, the address operator was put in place.

EDIT:
It might be worth to have a closer look at `DoSomething`, to determine, if the code is supposed to check for an empty string instead. But if the code passes all tests, I'd say, it's more likely that it can simply be removed.

Comment: Does nobody find it ironic we're speculating about the intent of **fake code** when it's the OP's job to post an [MCVE]?

Comment: @sleeptight: I'd say, it is enough of an MCVE to be answerable (and might even be an actual one). If it doesn't match the OP's actual code, thats his problem. But I've seen enough similar porting and refactoring artifacts, so it seems not unlikely to me that it DOES reflect the actual code well enough.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this make any sense?

No, it does not make sense. The address of a variable is never equal to `NULL`.

> could somebody explain some use case of this?

Perhaps it is an attempt to sanity check a broken compiler, or some UB within the code. In either case, I doubt it would be very effective.

With the assumption that the compiler is not broken, I see no use for the condition. And that is an assumption that most of us get to / must make every day.

---

As H. Guijt suggested, I also find it plausible that the check is a re factoring artefact that happened when a tired programmer changed the code to use `std::string` instead of a pointer, and then "fixed" the test to be syntactically correct, even though it is now meaningless.

Comment: Compiler is g44 4.8 ... so I think this is not the reason .. So basically the condition is always true as the address is nevel NULL so the DoSomething() will be always executed

Comment: @redobot surely that's not the only compiler the code will ever be compiled with :) Yes, you've got the idea.

Comment: @redobot A broken compiler is typically built with `--disable-bootstrap` (testing if the compiler can compile itself) or disabling other internal consistency checks. The version is irrelevant.

Comment: I imagine this is a conversion of older source code where raw character pointers were passed around. Far too many people seem to believe that using NULL for an empty string is somehow a good thing (it isn't), so you get these tests all over the place. After a refactoring to use std::string it might have been left in place accidentally.

Comment: @H.Guijt good point. Even though redobot didn't ask for how it directly, it might be worth considering how the code came to exist.

Answer (score -1):

No sense.

std::string mystring; is allocated in the stack.

so you're verifying the address of this variable allocated in the stack is not null. That's not possible unless there's a Weird memory corruption.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Basic_architecture_of_a_stack

Comment: It isn't *"allocated on the stack"*, as far as the programming language is concerned. It has either automatic storage duration, or static storage duration. How that is implemented, is up to the C++ implementation. Either way, though, it will always have an address other than `nullptr` in the code snippet posted.

Comment: Or even dynamically allocated if it's a member of an instance of a class and that instance was dynamically allocated.

Comment: @IInspectable: Although this is bit of-topic. Unless we know the scope of the variable we can't be very sure that *it isn't "allocated on the stack*. I guess `Automatic` has something to deal with `stack storage` and `Global` has something to deal with `static storage`.

Comment: @sameerkn C++ the language doesn't have the concept of "stack" as a memory area. That's an implementation detail. "Automatic storage duration" doesn't tell you where it will end up in memory: could be on the stack (if it's a function-local var), in static storage (if it's a member of a global variable), on the heap (if it's a member of a dynamically-allocated object). As far as the languages rules are concerned, what matters if storage duration, not the real memory where it ends up.

Comment: @sameerkn: You are asking for an implementation detail, that isn't interesting. I outlined the interesting facets: The object has automatic or static storage duration. And drew the conclusion that it always has an address other than `nullptr`.

Comment: @DavidHammen: If it is a class member, then it has automatic storage duration.

Comment: @Angew: Thanks for clearing things up and making me think the language and its features and facilities as abstraction.

Comment: If we have the declaration of the variable (std::string) and an IF clause of this variable, this variable must be part of a function, not a member of a class. Unless it's a composition of different parts. So in that case, what has no sense is trying to guess something.